# How to Test the IVR or Dialplan of Freeswitch using Sipp

Tags: freeswitch

I create a custom ivr in freeswitch. caller calls 11111 and routs to custom ivr. How can i test this ivr using  sipp tester? What does do for config freeswitch if requied and what is the sipp command line and scenario xml file for testing this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get that info in this article.

https://mojolingo.com/blog/2013/load-testing-voice-applications-with-sipp/